# qt c++ "QString::number" not retaining decimal places needed

Tags: c++, qt, numbers, qstring

I'm having trouble converting numbers to strings and retaining all of the decimal places. In the code below, both flat and flon are declared as double and have 6 decimal places (flat = 32.447134), (flon = -100.136468). After converting with QString::number, (flat = 32.4471), and (flon = -100.136). These are gps coordinates so it is very important to keep all of the decimal places.

If I shorten flon to -99.136468, it retains 4 decimal places after conversion, so it appears that there must be a limit to the length of the string of 8 characters. I need 11.

How can I convert them and retain all f the decimal places?

I have tried "QString::number(long n, int base = 10)" and others from the QT documentation but get syntax and other errors when I try to run.

Thanks in advance!

```
if (ui -> northeast -> isChecked())
       {
           flat = flat + .00007;
           flon = flon + .00007;
           lo = QString::number(flon);
           la = QString::number(flat);

           QString ll = la + "," + lo;
           ui -> gps_latlon -> setText(ll);
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [this overload of QString::number](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6):

```
QString QString::number(double n, char format, int precision)
```

So pass the correct format and your required precision.

Do it like this:

```
str = QString::number(flat, 'f', 6);
```

And if you're wondering what `f` means, [check it out here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#argument-formats).

Comment: Thank you very much! After many hours of attempting to decipher qt's cryptic instructions, I finally came up with this:   QString la = QString("%1").arg(flat,0,'f',6); I think I like yours better!

Comment: That's another way of doing it. Though a way costlier one, since constructing a QString is normally a costly thing to do.